# Comprobar disponibilidad email ¿Cómo sería con AJAX en tiempo real?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Deseo comprobar si existe un email o no, a la hora de registrar un usuario nuevo en la base de datos. Para ello tengo un formulario y las siguientes funciones.

**Código formulario HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_registrar.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_formulario.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
        <!--<h1>Formulario de Registro</h1>-->
        <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar_formulario();">
            <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
            <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                <!-- Por cada etiqueta de <input> <label for="id_mismo_que_input">XXXX: </label> -->             <!-- required para HTML5 -->
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event);">
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input-2">
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="idemail" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input-1">
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" maxlength="9" tabindex="4" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetrasNumeros(event);">
                <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="9" tabindex="5" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
                <br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input-2">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input-2">
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="registrar" class="registrar" tabindex="8"/>
                <?php
                    include "Clases/BD.php";
                    //Si pulsamos el botón "Registrar"...
                    if(isset($_POST["registrar"])){
                        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                        $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
                        $dni = $_POST["dni"];
                        $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
                        $idemail = $_POST["idemail"];
                        $password = $_POST["password"];

                        $idemails = BD::obtenerEmails();
                        if(in_array(strtolower($idemail), array_change_key_case($idemails,CASE_LOWER))){
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('El email ya existe.');</script>";
                        }else{
                            //Llamamos al método "insertarCliente" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                            BD::insertarCliente($idemail, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $telefono, $password);
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cliente guardado correctamente.');</script>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="iniciar_sesion_cliente.php">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--<div class="footer">
            <p>Copyrigth</p>
        </div>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**Funciones:**

```
static public function obtenerEmails(){
        //Realizamos la consulta.
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT idemail FROM clientes;";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        //Creamos una array de emails.
        $emails = array();
        //Mientras haya email los guardamos...
        while($email = $registro->fetch()){
            //Array asociativo: al array $emails le pasamos el email concreto.
            array_push($emails, $email["idemail"]);
        }
        //Devolvemos el array de emails.
        return $emails;
    }
```

A la hora de pulsar "Guardar" comprueba si existe o no. Todo correcto. **¿Cómo podría comprobarlo antes de pulsar "Guardar" a tiempo real en el mismo campo email? ¿Con AJAX?**

Comment: Hola, lo puedes hacer aplicando un evento `onblur` al input haciendo una consulta a la bd, dependiendo del resultado obtenido realizas las acciones deseadas, todo esto con ajax

Comment: Un posible ejemplo...

Comment: ¿Alguna ayuda @Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      $("#email").blur(function(){
        var email_data = $("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'destino donde se comprobara si la existencia del email',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                'data':email_data
            },
            success: function(data){
                // DONDE SE MOSTRARA EL MENSAJE
                $('#result').html(data); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un elemplo:

```
$(document).ready(documentoListo)
function documentoListo() {
    $("#email").blur(function(){//esperamos evento perdida de foco
        comprueba_email($(this).val())//llamamos la funcion y le pasamos el valor del input
    })
}
function comprueba_email(email){
    //con ajax enviamos el email mediante post a un archivo php
    $.ajax({
        url : 'comprobar_email.php',//ruta del archivo donte estara la consulta a la bd
        type : 'POST',
        cache : false,
        data : "email="+email,
        success: function(resultado){
            //hacer algo  con el resultado
        }
    });
}
```

y en el archivo php seria algo asi:

```
$coneccion=mi_coneccion_a_bd();
$email=$_POST["email"];//valor enviado desde ajax
$sql="SELECT ALGO FROM tabla WHERE EMAIL=?";
$preparar_sql=$coneccion->prepare($sql);
$preparar_sql->bind_param("s",$email);
$preparar_sql->execute();
$preparar_sql->store_result();
if($preparar_sql->num_rows > 0){
    echo "existe";
}else{
    echo "no existe";
}
$preparar_sql->close();
```

Comment: Lo siento pero tu código adaptado al mío no funciona... No me da ningún error pero siempre me lo admite, exista o no... ¿Alguno me da una posible solución?